# URL DE REFERENCIA + PARÂMETROS VIA GET

Tags: php, html

como eu consigo passar uma URL parecida com essa?

**Quero deixar algo parecido com isso:**

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**#comentarios?aprovado=true**

**Eu sei que dessa maneira abaixo, funciona corretamente os 2:**

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**?aprovado=true**

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**#comentarios**

porem eu queria mandar os 2 parâmetros via url, é possível?

O **objetivo** dessa url é, voltar a página para o **id** comentarios **E** receber um parâmetro $_GET["aprovado"]

**OBS:** ignore isso, **https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask** só peguei para complementar meu exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

**Solução**

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?aprovado=true&#comentarios

Não sabia que o & funcionava para esse caso.

OBS: Eu deleto o tópico ou mantenho?

Comment: Se possível mantenha. Caso outra pessoa tenha uma dúvida semelhante, poderá está resolvendo através dessa "thread".

Comment: Vou manter então, obrigado.